# Magento theme for /errors/report.php?

Tags: exception, magento

So I did an empty search through Advanced Search at here:

http://www.princessly.com/catalogsearch/advanced/

And Magento redirected me to here:

http://www.princessly.com/errors/report.php?id=693893419&skin=default

And when I click "Back" button to get back to http://www.princessly.com/catalogsearch/advanced/, it correctly gave me the error message: "Please specify at least one search term."

This is really weird.

My questions are:

1. Why did Magento not behave well by giving a nice error message at http://www.princessly.com/catalogsearch/advanced/ but rather redirected me to http://www.princessly.com/errors/report.php?id=693893419&skin=default ? This is not user-friendly IMHO.
2. How to specify a theme for the /errors/report.php page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I installed a theme which has a class file that has white spaces before the code begins, thus typical "headers already sent" error.

And one can change the theme of the error page by this guide: http://www.magentogoreview.com/custom-magento-theme-for-error-there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request~144

I found this by the help of this doc: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/there_has_been_an_error_processing_your_request